# ThreadLocal plus-equals (+=) in Java?

Tags: java, operators, thread-local

Programming noob here, so probably a dumb question, but there is no plus-equals (+=) operator for a ThreadLocal variable in Java, is there? This sort of thing works fine:

```
public static ThreadLocal<Double> tl = new ThreadLocal<>();
public double whatever;
//stuff here
double temp = tl.get()+whatever;
tl.set(temp);
```

Or replacing the last two lines with:

```
tl.set(tl.get()+whatever);
```

Just wanted to make sure there was no other way. It'd be nice if there were something like:

```
tl.add(whatever);
```

Comment: There is not such operator for Thread variable.

Comment: As `ThreadLocal` is of generic type (literally) there's no way such a method could have been provided. For example what would `add` be expected to do for `ThreadLocal<Date>`?

Comment: @Quota: Touché.

Comment: It's possible to define your own `ThreadLocalDouble` class that extends `ThreadLocal<Double>` and provides arithmetic operations like `add` to emulate `+` or `addTo` to emulate `+=`.  You can't redefine the operators in Java.  Doing this could make the rest of the code more readable.  I don't know whether anyone has already done this in an open-source library.

Answer (score 2):

ThreadLocal can contain and work with object of any provided type, so method "add" just is not "generic" enough. You can set your object, you can get your object, and having reference to it you can do whatever you need, but it is out of ThreadLocal responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you cannot perform the `+=` operation is because in Java, primitives are passed as value not reference.  What ends up happening when you call `.get()` is it returns a copy of the value being held not a pointer to the actual value.  So changing the returned value will have no effect.

You will need to utilize the `.set(tl.get()+x)` idiom that you describe.

Answer (score 1):

There is no operator overloading in Java. You can not do that. In the other hand in a language like C++ you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

In deed, there is no add-method in class ThreadLocal. Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).